# button in an mdl template in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, material-design, material-design-lite, cakephp-3.4

I am creating a cakephp blog essentially from the blog tutorial(in the official cakephp cookbook for version 3.4) and using a template from mdl(material design lite).
this is the one : [this one](https://getmdl.io/templates/blog/index.html)

I have two questions here...

1.I need to use the custom add button in the theme as a form button, is it possible , and if yes, is it recommended to do so and how...!

2.Should I use the view(already created) as the admin console and use this template as another view with the existing controller or should I modify the the view and fit the code from the mdl theme in this view.

I am sorry if I sound dumb but I am new to the framework

Comment: You'll probably hardly get any good answers, as there's lots of room for interpretation in your questions (what green button? what does "_connect to the controller method"_ mean? what's the actual programming related problem with that?), and you're probably using the wrong technical terms (the view is a whole layer that consists of view classes, helpers, cells, templates, and elements).

Comment: I am pointing to the blog tutorial in the official cook book..Does that help..?